# Simple Perl Script (Total Perl Noob, just starting out)

Tags: database, perl, dbi

I'm not in school or anything, but I have this example test that I want to complete. I'm not 100% sure where to begin (as said, I am completely new to Perl but really, really want to get into it).

Given a table 'mailing':

```
CREATE TABLE mailing (
    addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

The mailing table will initially be empty.  New addresses will be added on a daily basis.  It is expected that the table will store at least 10,000,000 email addresses and 100,000 domains.

Write a perl script that updates another table which holds a daily count of email addresses by their domain name.

Use this table to report the top 50 domains by count sorted by percentage growth of the last 30 days compared to the total.

**NOTE**
- You MUST use the provided `DB.pm` for all database interaction, and you must use it as it is (DB.pm cannot be modified except for the connection settings).

- The original mailing table should not be modified.
- All processing must be done in Perl (eg. no complex queries or sub-queries)

And here is the DB.pm

```
package GUI::DB;

use strict;
use DBI;

use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(dbConnect query);

#
# dbConnect - connect to the database, get the database handle
#
sub dbConnect {

        # Read database settings from config file:
        my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
        my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn,
                '',
                '',
                                { RaiseError => 1 } 
    );

        return $dbh;

}

#
# query - execute a query with parameters
#       query($dbh, $sql, @bindValues)
#
sub query {
        my $dbh = shift;
        my $sql = shift;
        my @bindValues = @_;            # 0 or several parameters

        my @returnData = ();

        # issue query
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        if ( @bindValues ) {
                $sth->execute(@bindValues);
        } else {
                $sth->execute();
        }

        if ( $sql =~ m/^select/i ) {
                while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                        push @returnData, $row;
                }
        }

        # finish the sql statement
        $sth->finish();

        return @returnData;
}

__END__
```

I work with PHP and fun stuff like that regularly, but Perl is just out there for me.

Comment: Is it going to be used for spaming :)?

Comment: What is DB.pm? Did you mean Perl's DBI?

Comment: Also I don't think anyone will write a program for you, show what you have come up so far and what is your problem and then people may help.

Comment: I am by no means asking anyone to write this for me, I'm only asking for a push in the right direction. I'll never learn if someone just writes it for me.

Comment: Voting to close the question. Even though the questioner might have good intentions, in its current form the question is more like an assignment for others than a request for help on a concrete problem of general interest. Here's one push in the right direction: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of Perl `DBI` usage that inserts a record into `mailing` table:

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:databasename', 'username', 'password'
               ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
$dbh->do('INSERT INTO mailing VALUES(?)', 'test@test.com');
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: I'm really kicking myself in the butt here, but up until this point, following along with a book, I've only ever run simple, easy to write scripts that can be run from Terminal. I've never used a database with .pm extension nor do I know how to set it up on my linux machine. Any help?

Comment: Turns out my book has a pretty lengthy chapter on DBI, so I'm going to read that thoroughly before asking any more questions. Thanks for the example though, going to keep that in mind when I actually finish this chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the rules state that you must use the `query` method from `DB.pm`, then:

```
my $dbh = dbConnect() or die "A horrible death";
query($dbh, "INSERT INTO Mailing(addr) VALUES(?)", 'someone@example.com');
```

The `DB.pm` module is defective in that it does not provide a error return indication - it relies on the DBI RaiseError to generate the error.  It also does not provide a way to terminate the database connection.

---

The code in DB.pm is flabby.  The `dbConnect()` method is:

```
sub dbConnect {

        # Read database settings from config file:
        my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
        my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn,
                '',
                '',
                                { RaiseError => 1 } 
    );

        return $dbh;

}
```

It could be:

```
sub dbConnect
{
        # Read database settings from config file:
        my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
        return DBI->connect($dsn, '', '', { RaiseError => 1 });
}
```

That's 6 lines instead of 13, and is actually easier to read than the original.

Comment: Even more flabby is the "if ( @bindValues )" in query(). It serves no useful purpose whatsoever...